# How to copy all files (rules, envs,..) called by a Snakefile into a new repository?

Tags: snakemake

I started to develop my Snakemake workflow following the guidelines of "Distribution and Reproducibility" (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html) to organize the repository folder. Over time, I ended up creating multiple workflows in that same directory which are sharing some rule files, envs, scripts, ...

I can easily call the different workflows using dedicated Snakefiles but the situation is not ideal when it comes e.g. to sharing a specific workflow with collaborators or when I need to crystalize a specific version of a workflow.

Is there a way to copy all (and only) the files called by a Snakefile into a new directory or repository?